# Find distorted rectangle in image (OpenCV)

Tags: image-processing, opencv, camera-calibration

I am looking for the right set of algorithms to solve this image processing problem:

- I have a distorted binary image containing a distorted rectangle
- I need to find a good approximation of the 4 corner points of this rectangle

I can calculate the contour using OpenCV, but as the image is distorted it will often contain more than 4 corner points. 
Is there a good approximation algorithm (preferably using OpenCV operations) to find the rectangle corner points using the binary image or the contour description?

The image looks like this:

[image]

Thanks!

Dennis

Comment: As always with such questions, sample images would be very helpful.

Comment: I added an image, I hope this will help finding a solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [cvApproxPoly](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#approxpoly) function to eliminate number of nodes of your contour, then filter out those contours that have too many nodes or have angles which much differ from 90 degrees. See also [similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6134109/how-do-i-find-a-rectangle-in-a-photo-using-iphone/6134693#6134693)

Answer (score 2):

little different answer, see

http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html

Comment: broken link :( (not surprising after 8 years... :) )

Answer (score 1):

Look at the opencv function ApproxPoly. It approximates a polygon from a contour.

Answer (score 1):

Try Harris Corner Detector. There is example in OpenCV package. You need to play with params for your image.

And see other OpenCV algorithms: http://www.comp.leeds.ac.uk/vision/opencv/opencvref_cv.html#cv_imgproc_features

Answer (score 0):

I would try generalised Hough Transform it is a bit slow but deals well with distorted/incomplete shapes.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform

Answer (score 0):

1. This will  work even if you start with some defects, i.e. your approxPolly call returns pent/hexagons. It will reduce any contour, transContours in example, to a quad, or whatever poly you wish.
2. ```
   vector<Point> cardPoly;// Quad storage
   int PolyLines = 0;//PolyPoly counter ;)
   double simplicity = 0.5;//Increment of adjustment, lower numbers may be more precise vs. high numbers being faster to cycle.
   while(PolyLines != 4)//Adjust this 
   {
       approxPolyDP(transContours, Poly, simplicity, true);
       PolyLines = Poly.size();
       simplicity += 0.5;
   }
   ```